# Import csv as a queue and then append / delete first item

Tags: python, csv, queue, append

```
import numpy as np
f = open('qdiff.csv','r')
queue1 = f.read()
queue = [queue1]
print(queue)

logB = 10
logTV = 9

diff = logB - logTV
queue.pop(0)
queue.append(diff)
mean = sum(queue) / len(queue)
std = np.std(queue)

print(queue)
```

showing only the newly appended value (1) not updating the original queue

Comment: You only read the file as a single string and put it in a list. You must read each line of the CSV as separate string and maybe convert it to another datatype. There is a module "csv" to help.

Comment: Thanks Michael, any idea how I would go about doing that - still very new to all this!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `pop()` operation removes all of the data from your csv.

`queue`, here is just a list consisting of one string that has all the data from the csv

To remove the first value you would need to split the string and provide a separator.
In your csv the separator is most likely a comma (`,`) or `\n`.

Try:

```
f = open('qdiff.csv','r')
queue1 = f.read()
queue = queue1.split(',')
queue = list(f)
queue.pop(0)
print(queue)
```

Comment: First you have to separate the lines (rows) of the file and some more things to repair.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried out the code you suggested and returned this error -     queue = queue.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Edited it. This should isolate the first value only after the split so you can remove it, But as @MichaelButscher mentioned, the rows have to be separated too.

Comment: @Ellon thanks for this not getting that error anymore. However it is telling me that the list is empty - although it is. The CSV file is only 1 row with multiple columns.